# Do PCs with Windows 10 and a display 3840 x 2160 have a standard method and easily preconfigured to display icons and fonts to the appropriate size?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display

I got some PC notebook that had a display of 3840 x 2160, but the icons of some apps are tiny: about 1/2 the width and 1/2 the height, so the icon is 1/4 as big. And some dialog box or window that can't have the font configured, the font size is also 1/4.

So I ended up not using the computer at all, and using something else.  But nowadays, if I buy a notebook PC with 3840 x 2160, does it already have an option in Windows 10 that can let all icons and fonts be 4x the size?  (Or is it readily configurable by the users -- although why should the user find a way to configure it instead of the manufacturer)

Comment: Look at the 'Scaling' options built into Windows 10.

Comment: You can also make Text bigger independent of scaling. When in "Scaling" Options, in the search box, type Make Text Size Bigger and there is an adjustment for text size

Comment: "Why should the user find a way to configure it?" - Well, because it's a customization that isn't unanimously set one way or the other, it's personal preference. The manufacturer sets a default and from there the user has the power to customize.

Comment: @TylerN that isn't true. On the Mac, they make it one size on non-Retina display, and then when on Retina display when it is so small that it is not easily seeable, they make it the double width and height.  That is what "makes sense". This is what Steve Jobs would do, instead of "well, a pixel is a pixel and if the customer want the icon that became tiny seeable, go customize it yourself, because I need to go home and count my money"

Answer (score 0):

> does it have an option in Windows 10 that can let all icons and fonts be 4x the size?

Yes, the `Scale and Layout` setting under `Display` settings.  Setting this to more than 100% will make all icons and text bigger.

You can always access the `Display` settings by right clicking the desktop and clicking display settings.

[image]